# PopupWindow at a specific coordinate with no anchor view

Tags: android, popupwindow

I have a custom ImageView and in the OnDraw I have added some bitmap overlays. I can capture the click event for any overlay using action up type event in the OnTouchEvent callback. The thing is for me to display a popup window I must supply a view anchor for the popup window to show but I am using **the bitmaps** as anchors **not** a particular view, so I am stuck. I cannot find any sollution on the web regarding this issue. Passing the parent ImageView and adding the overlay x-y offsets (with Gravity.NO_GRAVITY) are not producing the desired result(Also the window arrow will not point correctly). [image]

Comment: how do you show a popupwindow?

Comment: using showAtLocation (View parent, int gravity, int xOffset, int yOffset);

Comment: this should work, maybe your offsets are wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [PopupWindow.showAtLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAtLocation%28android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

The problem is that x/y params into that function is offset relative to Window, to which anchor view belongs. You can see it clearly from function's source, where nothing from 'parent' is used except of its window token.

```
public void showAtLocation(View parent, int gravity, int x, int y) {
    showAtLocation(parent.getWindowToken(), gravity, x, y);
}
```

So to make your offsets good, you have to determine anchor's position relative to its window.

For this, use

```
Rect rc = new Rect();
View.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rc);
int[] xy = new int[2];
View.getLocationInWindow(xy);
rc.offset(xy[0], xy[1]);
```

now you have

```
inx x = rc.left, y = rc.top;
```

This is point of your ImageView's left-top corner relative to its window.

Finally show your PopupWindow at location relative to this point, and it should display correctly on top of your ImageView.

Answer (score 2):

You referring to the below kind of view right...I would suggest you to follow the below link and implement the same in your case as well..If found difficult post ur comment and will get back to you..[MAPViewBallons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)

Comment: unable to post image due to new user status, please refer to the link Marci Căşvan